# What is the basic skeleton of a phpfox module?

Tags: module, workflow, structure, phpfox

I Want create a basic phpfox module, and I don't know where to start, searched the net but could not find the skeleton or a user guide to create a module or describing the structure or flow of a phpfox module. I'm not demanding here a book about creating phpfox module but could somebody please give a outline or skeleton of a phpfox module (starting point atleast) or atleast redirect me to a source where i could find it. Thanks. I'm using phpfox 3.4.1 with mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpFox is based on a modular system, which runs all of the common features we as users see when
we visit a phpFox website. It also contains libraries or libs as we will call it, which is the engine that
runs the skeleton of phpFox and its modules. The products core is designed to be a CMS (Content
Management System). If you were only to include the core engine and the few required Core modules
to run the product it would simply by a CMS. We bring in modules to introduce other features, which
once packed with a heap of them turn the CMS into a Social Networking Solution. With this in mind
we leave it up to the client to decide what sort of a site they would like to run and what sort of features
they really need to get their crowd interested in their site and what it has to offer. Since the core can
be stripped away from modules this leaves a lot of freedom for the script to evolve into other products
such as a Software Licensing System or a Bug Tracker.

The modules are based on a MVC (Model View Controller) architectural pattern. phpFox is developed
under a OOP (Object—oriented programming) environment, which will give future developers an easier
time to enhance the product to their benefits.

Requirements for the product have become more flexible when dealing with PHP related
requirements such as safe_mode or open_base_dir. Using those as an example the product can work
with whatever those are set to allowing clients not to worry about if their server has a specific setting
enabled or not. Our goal is to have a product that is as flexible as possible to make sure it works on
all of the popular hosts today. There is one strict requirement and that in order to run the product you
must have PHP5. Past requirements have been PHP 4.3.3, however since PHP5 introduced a wave
of improvements when it comes down to OOP we decided it was time we move forward. As for
MySQL the same 4.1 is required, although phpFox will support other database drivers and not just
MySQL.

When reading this manual it is wise to read everything in order and not skip ahead as items that we
cover later on will require knowledge of something you have learned earlier in the manual.

Comment: Thank you so much..I had gien up on it..but with this help , it looks like , i can dig more into it..it's a great help..thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

PhpFox really has a dedicated KB section for the purpose of understanding structure of a module, you can find it here http://www.phpfox.com/kb/category/9/developer-documentation/ .

But there is a problem that you need to be a customer of Phpfox (you buy their product) to view these sections. I have  used it; in my opinion, it is very useful. So I think you should take a try on that.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur response.. but i'm not a customer of PHpfox, I just want to develop my skills, worked for a week for someone else and quite liked it, so wanted to dig in a bit more.