# Is there any developer guide for phpfox which helps me to buld custum phpfox website?

Tags: phpfox

Hi i am looking for a guide so that i can build my first phpfox website.Although i have download the phpfox edition and successfully configure on local system.

Answer (score 0):

I have already post an answer here [What is the basic skeleton of a phpfox module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721269/what-is-the-basic-skeleton-of-a-phpfox-module) you can take a look to see whether it could solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [phpfox api](http://www.phpfox.com/phpapi/) and [phpfox knowledge base](http://www.phpfox.com/kb/) for reference they will help you a lot